# Best practice device or usecase specific import?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm currently working on a python data science project. The pipeline consists of 10 different steps, whereby one specific is based on AI implemented in PyTorch. Since the calculation of some steps is very time expensive, we are currently implementing a Redis RQ worker setup to schedule over multiple machines. Since not all machines are equipped with a GPU we split up two queues, one for CPU tasks and one for GPU tasks.
So far so good.
The problem is that on CPU-only machines not all libraries are available, e.g. torch. Of course, that could be installed, however they are not needed. So I currently facing the question:

Which is the best way to handle the different imports between a GPU worker and a CPU worker?

All ten calculation steps are implemented in the main class of a "dataset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, you could make a config.py, where you have a hard coded define, e.g. `HAVE_GPU=True` for the GPU-equipped machines, import that first thing everywhere in your code, and based on that variable, decide which imports to make.

**config.py**

```py
HAVE_GPU = True
```

**some_script.py**

```py
import config
if config.HAVE_GPU:
    import gpurelatedmodules
else:
    import cpurelatedmodules
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. I also thought about this. Do you think it makes sense to implement an "importAll.py", which summarizes all imports?

Comment: @PeterAlgoMaker if you need the same imports in all your scripts, or have some imports that all scripts need. that makes sense.